# copy excel range to outlook mail body in C#

Tags: c#, outlook, office-interop, excel-interop, office-automation

```
Static void Main(string[] args)
{
    EXCEL.Application aap = new EXCEL.Application();
    string filelocation = "C:\\AdventureWorks_Sales.xlsx";
    Workbook wrkbok = aap.Workbooks.Open(filelocation);
    Worksheet sheet1 = wrkbok.ActiveSheet;
    Range rng= sheet1.Range["A1","G10"];
           

    Outlook.Application outlookapp = new Outlook.Application();
    Outlook.NameSpace nameSpace = outlookapp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
    nameSpace.Logon("", "",Missing.Value,Missing.Value);

    Outlook.MailItem mail = (Outlook.MailItem)outlookapp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

    mail.Body = rng.PasteSpecial();
    mail.To=("ddd@gmail.com");
    mail.Send();         
}
```

How can I paste the Excel range to the email body. As email body is string and below doesn't work

```
mail.Body = rng.PasteSpecial();
```

Comment: Use the HTMLBody property https://learn.microsoft.com/fi-fi/office/vba/api/Outlook.MailItem.HTMLBody

Comment: @MikaelKajander I tried using HTMLBody but not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a plain-text `Body` property:

```
mail.Body = rng.PasteSpecial();
```

You can use two main ways for building the message body based on the Excel data.  The first way is based on the `HTMLBody` property which represents an HTML document. In that case you are responsible to build the HTML document structure based on the Excel data that you need to paste. See [Paste Excel range to Outlook email body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47924211/paste-excel-range-to-outlook-email-body) for more information.

But the most easiest solution is to use the Word object model. The [WordEditor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.inspector.wordeditor) property returns the Microsoft Word Document Object Model of the message being displayed. So, you can paste directly to the document all the necessary data. See the [Selection.Paste](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.selection.paste) method which inserts the contents of the Clipboard at the specified selection. Using this method replaces the contents of the current selection. If you don't want to replace the contents of the selection, use the `Collapse` method before using this method. When you use this method with a `Range` object, the range expands to include the contents of the `Clipboard`. When you use this method with a `Selection` object, the selection does not expand to include the `Clipboard` contents; instead, the selection is positioned after the pasted `Clipboard` contents.

Comment: thanks for assistance. I can do using HTMLBody. but it's challenging to use WordEditor. so if you can provide code example would helpful.

Comment: can you please provide some code. it will be very helpful to me.

Comment: See [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012(v=office.12).aspx)