# Mailing list - take body and attachements from varous file paths and combine to email

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following excel file that I would like to use as mailing list for the users:

[image]

I would like excel to add up to 3 files (column N:P) as attachments and then content of the word document (column L) as the body of the email.

I have tried code by [Ron de Bruin](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/amail6.htm),
[paran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47924211/paste-excel-range-to-outlook-email-body). Currently my code is closest  to the one advised by [Tomasz Płociński](https://simpleexcelvba.com/send-word-document-as-email-body/).

Below code is a copy and paste from various posts and articles, however it does not work at all and unfortunately I do not have the knowledge to find where it is wrong.

```
Sub MAIL_EN)

On Error Resume Next
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim wd As Object
Dim doc As Object
Dim editor As Object
Dim i As Integer
Dim rng As Range

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
Set wd = CreateObject("Word.Application")

''
Set rng = Nothing
On Error Resume Next
Set rng = Worksheets("ank").Range(".Cells(i, 14).Value:.Cells(i, 16).Value").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
On Error GoTo 0
'''

For i = 17 To lastRow

    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    
        With OutMail
        .SentOnBehalfOfName = "mail@mail.com"
        .to = .Cells(i, 3).Value
        .CC = .Cells(i, 5).Value
        .BCC = .Cells(i, 6).Value
        .Subject = .Cells(i, 11).Value
        .Attachments.Add = rng
        Set doc = wd.documents.Open.Cells(i, 12).Value
        doc.Content.Copy

        Set editor = .GetInspector.WordEditor
        editor.Content.Paste
      
    
        Set wd = Nothing
       .Display
           
           
 doc.Close 0
 Set OutMail = Nothing
 Set wd = Nothing
 Set OutApp = Nothing
                    
End With

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: `Set rng = Worksheets("ank").Range(...` is outside the loop but `.Attachments.Add = rng` is wrong anyway. Loop through columns attaching each file individully eg `For j = 14 To 16: If Len(.Cells(i, j)) > 0 Then .Attachments.Add .Cells(i, j): Next`

Comment: @CPD1802        Link to code here: https://pasteboard.co/919LMsi1aV8K.png  ; still no response whatsoever.  Any idea why ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to complete my file using below code:

```
Sub Wysylanie_maili()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim tempfile As String
    Dim bodytext As String
    Dim wdApp As Object
    Dim wdDoc As Object
    Dim tempdoc As String
    
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim FileCell As Range
    Dim rng1 As Range
    
    
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    Set sh = Sheets("Generowanie")
    
    
   ' On Error Resume Next
    
    'loop
    For Each rng In Range("A14", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        
        'create mail
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        With OutMail
            .SentOnBehalfOfName = "mail@mail.pl"
            .To = rng.Offset(0, 2).Value
            .CC = rng.Offset(0, 3).Value
            .BCC = rng.Offset(0, 4).Value
            .Subject = rng.Offset(0, 9).Value
            
            'add files
            If Not IsEmpty(rng.Offset(0, 10).Value) Then
                .Attachments.Add (rng.Offset(0, 10).Value)
            End If
            
            If Not IsEmpty(rng.Offset(0, 11).Value) Then
                .Attachments.Add (rng.Offset(0, 11).Value)
            End If
            
            If Not IsEmpty(rng.Offset(0, 12).Value) Then
                .Attachments.Add (rng.Offset(0, 12).Value)
            End If
            
            If Not IsEmpty(rng.Offset(0, 13).Value) Then
                .Attachments.Add (rng.Offset(0, 13).Value)
            End If
            
            If Not IsEmpty(rng.Offset(0, 14).Value) Then
                .Attachments.Add (rng.Offset(0, 14).Value)
            End If
            
            If Not IsEmpty(rng.Offset(0, 15).Value) Then
                .Attachments.Add (rng.Offset(0, 15).Value)
            End If
            
            If Not IsEmpty(rng.Offset(0, 16).Value) Then
                .Attachments.Add (rng.Offset(0, 16).Value)
            End If
            
            If Not IsEmpty(rng.Offset(0, 17).Value) Then
                .Attachments.Add (rng.Offset(0, 17).Value)
            End If
            
            If Not IsEmpty(rng.Offset(0, 18).Value) Then
                .Attachments.Add (rng.Offset(0, 18).Value)
            End If
            
            If Not IsEmpty(rng.Offset(0, 19).Value) Then
                .Attachments.Add (rng.Offset(0, 19).Value)
            End If
            
                        
            'open word doc
            Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
            tempdoc = rng.Offset(0, 8).Value
            Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(tempdoc, ReadOnly:=True)
            
            'copy and paste to mail
            wdDoc.Content.Copy
            .HTMLBody = "<html><body>" & .HTMLBody & "</body></html>"
            .GetInspector().WordEditor.Range.PasteAndFormat wdFormatOriginalFormatting
            
             With WordEditor.Range.Find
                .Text = "Szanowni," '<-dears
                .Replacement.Text = (rng.Offset(0, 17).Value) '<- replace dears with column value , names
                .Wrap = 1
                .Forward = True
                .Format = False
                .MatchCase = False
                .MatchWholeWord = False
                .MatchWildcards = False
                .MatchSoundsLike = False
                .MatchAllWordForms = False
                .Execute Replace:=2
            End With
            
            'close word and delete temp file
            wdDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False
            wdApp.Quit
            Set wdDoc = Nothing
            Set wdApp = Nothing
            DoEvents 'wait for word to close
            If fso.FileExists(tempfile) Then
                On Error Resume Next
                fso.DeleteFile tempfile
                On Error GoTo 0
            End If
            
           
            .Display
            
        End With
        
        'Move to the next row of data
        Set OutMail = Nothing
        Set rng = rng.Offset(1, 0)
        
    Next rng
    
    'Clean up
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

I didn't know how to add variable amount of attachments , so I have max 7 of them as I will not need more.

Hope this comes handy to someone who may need it.

Much appreciate your answers.
Kind regards
Piotr